# If I deal multiple types of damage, do I need to deal them in the order listed?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

Consider a power like Fanatic's "Exorcism":

> Fanatic deals 1 target 1 melee damage and 1 radiant damage.

Can I choose to deal the radiant damage before the melee damage? Or do I have to deal the melee damage first because it is listed first? This would be important if I have an effect that deals bonus damage to the next damage that I deal, and one of the two damage types is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Effects on cards that are separated by an "and" happen sequentially, so the melee damage will happen before the radiant damage.**

From user phantaskippy (tagged as playtester) on the *Sentinels of the Multiverse* [game forums](https://greaterthangames.com/forum/topic/kaargra-warfang-timing-question-6469):

> Any use of "and" will happen sequentially. . . . All uses of "and" in situations where timing is relevant are intended to be sequential. It may not be obvious, but it is at least consistent.

This sentiment is repeated [here](https://greaterthangames.com/forum/topic/kismet-unsubtle-trickster-rule-question-8421) by user Rabit (tagged as moderator and playtester) among the discussions about effect timing:

> Do things in the order described.

In reading through forum posts, the consensus follows this interpretation.

---

To answer the question about why this may be important, that is, you want to increase one damage type for a specific reason, Adam the Admin has [this to say over on the forums](https://greaterthangames.com/forum/topic/fanatics-exorcism-power) (emphasis mine):

> The damage is intended to be dealt individually. **This means if it's increased, both melee and radiant are increased by 1 separately, and the same goes for when it's decreased.** A base reduction of -1 will make her do no damage at all, but a +1 will double her output. It essentially makes damage modifiers into multipliers for her innate power, which is in keeping with Fanatic being a high-risk/high-reward character.

So if you are looking to increase the radiant damage, you're in luck. Any increase to Fanatic's damage output will increase both the melee and radiant damage.

Comment: Does "moderator" just mean forum moderator? If so, is there any reason that a moderator's word weigh more strongly (aside from also being a playtester)?

Comment: @Thunderforge I would tend to think that forum moderators tend to have more knowledge about the game because they spend so much time parsing through forum posts to make sure everything is running smoothly. Ultimately, it doesn't look like the game designers step into the forum for any reason; they leave rules explanations up to people with higher rankings in the forums.

Comment: @Thunderforge - The computer version of the game works this way as well (damage types done in order, each type modified individually)